# What is the difference between evolutionary game theory and meta-heuristics?

Tags: comparison, evolutionary-algorithms, game-theory

Here is a [list of meta-heuristic algorithms](https://www.researchgate.net/post/List_of_metaheuristics_algorithms)

- Ant colony optimization,
- Ant lion optimizer,
- Artificial bee colony algorithm,
- Bat algorithm,
- Cat swarm optimization,
- Crow search algorithm,
- Cuckoo optimization algorithm,
- Cuckoo search algorithm,
- Differential evolution,
- Firefly algorithm,
- Genetic algorithm,
- Glowworm swarm optimization,
- Gravitational search algorithm,
- Grey wolf optimizer,
- Harmony search,
- Multi-verse optimizer,
- Particle swarm optimization,
- Shuffled complex evolution,
- Simulated annealing,
- Tabu search,
- Teaching-learning-based optimization

Can anyone explain the similarities and dissimilarities of evolutionary game theory and the meta-heuristic approach?